# Configure local typescript compiler inside package.json

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, visual-studio-code, tsconfig

**EDIT** *#1*: seems like I have a working configuration, all suggestions to improve this are welcome though. See answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42269408/1155847

---

**ORIGINAL QUESTION**:

I'm currently trying to setup my environment so that my `package.json`'s `devDependencies` typescript version will be used. What are some of the best practices for this, so that it is "editor unaware" and preferably can be used as an npm script, e.g.: `npm run tscompile`?

To be clear - I can get everything working when using `npm install typescript -g` - but then I'm relying on a global installed version, whic is not what I want - as we'll want to work in a team and set on a specific typescript version for each member before upgrading, so we're all on the same page.

I'm currently trying to set it up like this - yet `npm` then complains it doesn't recognize "node_modules" as an internal or external command... I presume I do have to pass the tsconfig.json to tsc as well, or at least give it the "working directory" - but I can't even get past launching tsc from my locally downloaded npm cache.

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "tswithnodejsgettingstarted",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app/index.js",
    "tscompile": "node_modules/typescript/tsc"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "2.1.6"
  }
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
    "compileOnSave": true,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outDir": "app"
    },
    "include": [
        "src/**/*.ts"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok... It seems like it was as simple as this (see below). Answering it here, for anyone else looking for the answer. Or please let me know **if there are better solutions**.

Configure the script like `"tsc": "tsc"` inside `package.json`. Then just run `npm run tsc` and it will use your tsc version you have installed locally, and discover your tsconfig.json of course. It doesn't use your global version - as I uninstalled that one - just entering `tsc` in the command line errors out.

E.g.:

Check the [repo](https://github.com/pluralsight-courses/typescript-fundamentals/tree/master/001-GettingStarted)* where I was playing with this.

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "tscnodejsgettingstarted",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npm run tsc && node app/index.js",
    "tsc": "tsc"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "2.1.6"
  }
}
```

---

*repo: https://github.com/pluralsight-courses/typescript-fundamentals/tree/master/001-GettingStarted

Answer (score 6):

You can also use the `prestart` script. By default it runs before the start command (see all the default scripts that you can set up [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts)).

```
  "scripts": {
    "prestart": "npm run tsc",
    "start": "node app/index.js",
    "tsc": "tsc"
  }
```